# List Items with alternating colours

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have my template file which has data being populated into it. However I want to be able to write a class to every odd list element.

The issue i have is that some of the fields being listed are hidden when there is no data and as such i cannot simply write in the class of every other element.

I know I could do this using javascript, but would prefer not to.

Is there any way I can use the page_prerender to look at which list items are going to be displayed and add a class to each odd element?

for example my template looks like this but with many more fields:

```
    <ul>
    <li>
    <h3>Data title</h3>
    <p><%=GetDymanicData1 %></p>
    </li>
<!-- if statement to check if data has value, else do not show -->
    <li>
    <h3>Data title</h3>
    <p><%=GetDymanicData2 %></p>
    </li>
    <li>
    <h3>Data title</h3>
    <p><%=GetDymanicData2 %></p>
    </li>
    ...
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Description

This is not `c#` this is a question about `html` and `css`.

You can do this in pure `css`. Check out my sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/pFpbW/)

#### Sample

**CSS**

```
li:first-child {background: #FF0}
li:nth-child(2n+3) {background: #CCC}
```

Comment: Actually, for all my work in CSS for god only know how many years, I didn't think of that. Sometimes, the simplest answer is always the best one. I'll give this a try.

Comment: Although, it doesn't work in IE8 and below, I still think its a viable solution.

Comment: :( right, maybe you will combine this with a jQuery solution for IE8 ?

Comment: This is exactly what I plan to do. use the css rule for all other browsers except if IE i will add some jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Repeater control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx

The repeater supports supplying a template for each of your data items, as well as an alternating item template, which is applied to every other item in the item list.  An example can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.alternatingitemtemplate.aspx

Comment: Or follow dknaack's advice with css :) To be honest, this type of problem is really best handled with straight css.